# Getting “keystore.keyAlias” is not allowed to be empty error while building app apk from expo client

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have entered the alias, when I press enter it goes to new line and is stuck.
Pressing enter again asks for key password, I enter it and press enter and the error is displayed.
“keystore.keyAlias” is not allowed to be empty

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When it remains blocked, you just have to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, it will ask you for the alias again, and this time it will no longer remain blocked